# Why setCustomValidity() not working in React app?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Why `setCustomValidity()` doesn't work in React? Am I missing something? With vanillia HTML and JS works fine. Or there is other way to easily make something similiar to `setCustomValidity`?

React code:

```
class Form extends React.Component {
  formVal(e) {
    e.target.setCustomValidity("Test_1");
  }
  formVal2() {
    let inpt = document.getElementById("input");
    inpt.target.setCustomValidity("TEST_2");
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <input
            id="input"
            type="datetime-local"
            onBlur={this.formVal}
          />
        </form>
        <button onClick={this.formVal2}>Click </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[CodePen - React](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vZPyVJ)

With no React:

```
<form>
  <input type="email" id="mail" name="mail">
  <button onclick="test()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

// JS

```
var input = document.getElementById("mail");
function test() {
 input.setCustomValidity("test")
}
```

[CodePen - no React](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gRELZv)

Comment: Check function formVal2, you don't need `.target`

Comment: @Mikalai you're right, but still not working. And getting element via `document.getElementById()` is not recomended in React.

Answer (score 19):

`setCustomValidity` doesn't immediately trigger validation, you have to have a form submit event to trigger it or call `checkValidity`. I've updated your [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oeoxoR) to show how you can achieve this in React, and it is also included below.

```js
class Form extends React.Component {
  
  onChange(e) {
    let date = new Date(Date.parse(e.target.value));
    
    if (date > new Date()) {
      e.target.setCustomValidity("Please select a date in the past."); 
    } else {
      e.target.setCustomValidity("");
    }
  }
    
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <input
            id="input"
            type="datetime-local"
            onChange={this.onChange}
          />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Form />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Note that, on Mac, Chrome, Error msg won't be visible if the field is not in the viewport while submitting the form! If the field is visible on the viewport then only we can see the proper message, otherwise, that resp field will be focused but the error msg won't be there!

Answer (score 4):

In case you want to show validation for required fields that are left empty you should set setCustomValidity on onInvalid like this:

```
<input onInvalid={e => e.target.setCustomValidity('Your custom message')} />
```

And if you are using typescript like this:

```
<input onInvalid={e => (e.target as HTMLInputElement).setCustomValidity('Enter User Name Here')} />
```

In case you are want to handle validation for values you can add it like here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45695707/6912349

Answer (score 3):

Hello here is how you need to do it.

```js
import * as React from "react";

export default function Form () {
  const nameInput = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const [nameVal,setNameVal] = React.useState("");

  const onSubmitHandler = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
   // handle yow submition
  }

  const onNameChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (!nameInput.current) return;

    setNameVal(e.currentTarget.value);
    const {validity} = nameInput.current;

    if (validity.badInput) {
      nameInput.current.setCustomValidity("Set the message to show");
    }

    if (validity.customError) {
      nameInput.current.setCustomValidity("Set the message to show");
    }

    if (validity.patternMismatch) {
      nameInput.current.setCustomValidity("Set the message to show");
    }

    if (validity.rangeOverflow) {
      nameInput.current.setCustomValidity("Set the message to show");
    }

    if (validity.rangeUnderflow) {
      nameInput.current.setCustomValidity("Set the message to show");
    }

    if (validity.stepMismatch) {
      nameInput.current.setCustomValidity("Set the message to show");
    }

    if (validity.tooLong) {
      nameInput.current.setCustomValidity("Set the message to show");
    }

    if (validity.tooShort) {
      nameInput.current.setCustomValidity("Set the message to show");
    }

    if (validity.typeMismatch) {
      nameInput.current.setCustomValidity("Set the message to show");
    }

    if (validity.valid) {
      nameInput.current.setCustomValidity("Set the message to show");
    }

    if (validity.valueMissing) {
      nameInput.current.setCustomValidity("Set the message to show");
    }

  
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmitHandler}>
     <label htmlFor="id-name">Name</label>
     <input
        id="id-name"
        ref={nameInput}
        type="text"
        required
        min={5}
        max={15}
        value={nameVal}
        onChange={onNameChange}
      />
      <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
  )
  
}
```

I mean you dont have to add all of them, just the ones you care about

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

```
<input required onInvalid={(e)=>{e.target.setCustomValidity('Your custom validation message here')}} />
```

Answer (score 0):

With the hooks [useEffect](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) and [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref), it can be achieved by wrapping the `<input>` in a custom component :

```
function ExtendedInput ({ customValidity, ...downProps }) {
  const ref = useRef(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    if (customValidity !== undefined && ref.current !== null) {
      ref.current.setCustomValidity(customValidity)
    }
  }, [customValidity])
  return <input
    ref={ ref }
    { ...downProps }
  />
}
```

And to pass the wanted message as a prop :

```
<ExtendedInput
  type="text"
  value="a value"
  customValidity="it is not valid"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //REACT v17.0.2

import React from "react";
export default function test() {
  // To Validate 10 digit Mobile Number
  const onChangemob = (e) => {
    if (e.target.value.length == 10) {
      e.target.setCustomValidity("");
    } else {
      e.target.setCustomValidity("Please Enter Valid Mobile Number");
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input
          type="number"
          onKeyUp={onChangemob}
          placeholder="MOBILE NUMBER"
        />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).